# Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction: ConnectionWrapper is not visible from class loader

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have the following error that gives me the application, hibernate 3 use and gives me when I try to access a query repeatedly and I could not put the fix below DAOImpl and where I call the method multiple times, if someone could help me I would appreciate thanks for your time: :

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" 
org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException:
Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction;
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
interface org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionWrapper is not visible from class loader
```

And the method is

```
 public void checkattentiontable(){

     for (int i = 0; i < listaoffice.size(); i++) {

      if(i ==0){cantini0 = generalServices.cantAtenttionONtable(listaoffice.get(0));}
      if(i ==1){cantini1 = generalServices.cantAtenttionONtable(listaoffice.get(1));}
      if(i ==2){cantini2 = generalServices.cantAtenttionONtable(listaoffice.get(2));}
      if(i ==3){cantini3 = generalServices.cantAtenttionONtable(listaoffice.get(3));}
      if(i ==4){cantini4 = generalServices.cantAtenttionONtable(listaoffice.get(4));}
      if(i ==5){cantini5 = generalServices.cantAtenttionONtable(listaoffice.get(5));}
      if(i ==6){cantini6 = generalServices.cantAtenttionONtable(listaoffice.get(6));}
      if(i ==7){cantini7 = generalServices.cantAtenttionONtable(listaoffice.get(7));}
      if(i ==8){cantini8 = generalServices.cantAtenttionONtable(listaoffice.get(8));}
     }

     Timer timer = new Timer(5000, new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            if (cantinicialofice0 != cantini0) {
                officetoupdate = 0;
                cantinicialofice0 = cantini0;
                updateindicadores(); //INSIDE THIS I ACCESS TO OTHER QUERYS                 
            }


        }
    });

     timer.start();
     timer.setRepeats(true);

 }
```

Comment: what error messages saying ?

Comment: Check your connection related parameters like database url, username and password

Comment: Perhaps it is related to [HHH-3529: ConnectionWrapper is not visible from class loader](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-3529)?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Hibernate 3.2.6/3.3.1, it is likely the cause of the problem is a bug in Hibernate:

**[HHH-3529: ConnectionWrapper is not visible from class loader](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-3529)**

Looks like there's a bug in the `BorrowedConnectionProxy` class regarding the `getProxyClassLoader()` method.

Upgrade Hibernate to 3.5.0 or later. If that's not possible, there's a patch in that JIRA you can apply.